# Application that provides unique keys to multiple processes

Tags: c, multithreading

Any idea on how to build an application that provides unique keys each time it get called by another process.
Calling process isn't my problem here, my problem is how to sync between two(or more) processes and preventing it from providing the same key to both of them.

I'd really appreciate your help in this issue, please only outline the solution and I'll try to implement it.

Answer (score 10):

Just use a GUID as your key. It's universally unique.

Comment: Or just use `getpid()` if you're on UNIX/Linux

Comment: If you use GUID, make sure that you are using a thread-safe call in your programming language of choice.

Answer (score 1):

not to be to basic but why not just have an incrementing integer (ack a global) for your key. Have it initialize at start up. Save the calling process and key in a dictionary if you need the reference both ways. You could do this with a class, or store it in a database depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used C in ages, but there must be some way to synchronize your code so only one processes, or thread, can get into it at one time.  Something like:

```
int unique_index = 0;

synchronized int GetUnique()  {
    int i = unique_index++;
    return i;
}
```

You'd want to make sure `unique_index` was accessed *only* from within `GetUnique` or other synchronized code.  If it gets called from 10,000 threads all at the same time, you might experience some delays and you'd need something more clever, but that should do for a start.

If this program is to start and stop and deliver unique numbers to other programs, you'd need to make sure `GetUnique` would not do anything until the program was up and had recovered its data (`unique_index`) from a file or where ever.  Likewise, `GetUnique` would have to stop responding *before* data was saved during shutdown.